# using spring transaction management with select queries

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I am running a web portal using Spring MVC and JDBCTemplate. There are mostly multiple select queries (on single request also) running on the application (according to application scope).

After understanding Spring Transaction Management, I got that it ensures application transactions that include multiple insert will be fail-safe.

So, will there be any advantages of using spring transaction management in my scenario.

one method of my service layer.

```
public Map<String, Object> getVendorDocuments(String vendorEmail) {
        logger.info("Entered");
        DocumentPojo vendorDocment = null;
        List<InvoicePojo> invoicesList = null;
        Map<String, Object> vendorDocList = new HashMap<>();
        //Call vendor api method to bean of vendor registration documents
        try {
            vendorDocment = vendorDAO.getDocument(vendorEmail);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getCause().getMessage());
        }
        logger.debug("check whether vendorDocument is null=>"+vendorDocment);
        vendorDocList.put("vendorDoc", vendorDocment);

        //call admin api method to getlist of vendor invoices
        try {
            invoicesList = adminDAO.getInvoicesList(vendorEmail);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getCause().getMessage());
        }
        logger.debug("check whether vendor Invoices is null=>"+invoicesList);
        vendorDocList.put("invoices", invoicesList);

        logger.info("Exit");
        return vendorDocList;
    }
```

EDIT: My Question is about Spring Transaction Framework not Database Transaction

Comment: @AdamSmith: Above Question referes to Database Transaction but the question is about whether to use Spring Transaction Framework or not

Comment: @ankitjava that's the same thing. Spring transactions always end up delegating to the database for transaction handling. If it didn't, spring transactions would be useless and do nothing.

Comment: ok thanks @JBNizet  and AdamSmith